# Symfony 2 How do I embed collection form using some criterias

Tags: forms, collections, symfony, embed

I have a problem using the embed collection forms because I want to filter the data displayed on the collection given. i.e.

```
<?php
Class Parent
{
    ... some attributes ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Child", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"all"})
     */
     private $children;

    ... some setters & getters ...

}

Class Child
{
    private $attribute1;

    private $attribute2;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Parent", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     private $parent;

     ... some setters & getters ...
}
```

Then I build the form using:

```
class ParentChildType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('children', 'collection', array(
            'type' => ChildrenType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
        ));
    }
}
...
On controller:

    $parent = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Parent')->find( $id );
    $forms = $this->createForm( new ParentChildType(), $parent)->createView();

    and then..

    return array('forms' => $forms->crateView());
```

My problem is when I want to filter the collection by `$attribute1` and/or `$attribute2` of `Child` model class.

**There's a way to filter by a criteria for this collection forms?**

Comment: Normally you would use a query when loading $parent and load in just the children you want.  $parent = $repo->load($id,$params);  More of a model issue than a form issue.

Comment: But in the model I don't have the problem, the problem is when I want to use it like a Collection Type Form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's seems that I have to filter the object before using CreateQuery and then create the form using this filtered object.
Like this:

```
$parent = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
            SELECT p, c 
            FROM AcmeBundle:Parent p
            JOIN p.children c
            WHERE c.attribute1 = :attr1
              AND c.attribute2 = :attr2
           ")
           ->setParameter('attr1', <some_value>)
           ->setParameter('attr2', <some_value>)
           ->getOneOrNullResult();
$forms = $this->createForm( new ParentChildType(), $parent)->createView();
....
return array('forms' => $form->createView());
```

Answer (score 0):

I point you to right direction (I hope) :

http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/08/symfony2-ajax-form-republish/

This article deals with field dependencies. for example, when you select a country, you have the towns that belongs to the country that appears in the list.

It's seems it looks like your problem

Comment: Exactly! That example can be useful to solve my problem, however, I want to use it on "collection" type form.

Comment: Thank you, that example will be very useful

Comment: When i tried to access http://aulatic.16mb.com/wordpress/2011/08/symfony2-dynamic-forms-an-event-driven-approach/, there was a 403 Forbidden error. I really am eager to see the example because i have the same functionality.